# WCF AJAX enabled service created OK, but method returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, wcf

This is my first WCF service, so please be understanding. :)

- I have an existing ASP.Net web site that has been running OK so far.
- Using VS 2017 I added a new WCF Ajax enabled service.
- VS created the .svc and .cs files and it also made cahnges to the web.config.
- I made sure that HTTP activation is enabled in server roles.

When navigating to the service url via browser, the service page loads. OK.
When I try to add "/DoWork" to access the method that was created as the default, i get a 404 error.

I have been going CRAZY trying different tutorial suggestions. NOTHING WORKS.
I must be missing something simple. Something maybe is not enabled at server level?
I would think that the WCF code that was added by VS would work as it, right?

WHY 404?????
What am I missing????

Thank you for any help and best regards,

Udar

Comment: what does your full url look like? do you specify behaviour before the method name as well there?

Comment: I am using the url that would take me to the service and the method.

https://www.websiteaddress.com/MyService.svc                   == this one loads OK
https://www.websiteaddress.com/MyService.svc/DoWork     == 404

These are the urls I enter in my browser to test. 

Again, this is based on the code and web.config changes that Visual Studio 2017 adds by default when adding a WCF Ajax Enabled service to an existing ASP.NET web site.

Comment: can you maybe share `web.config` (at least all relevant non-sensitive bits) here?

Comment: Sure and thank you. Again, this section was auto-created by VS and I would think it would create all necessary data so the demo service runs out of the box.

Comment: Hi,has the problem been solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use webhttpbinding, you need to add webHttp to the endpoint behavior:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ESEndPointBehavior">
                    <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

This is my configuration file, and I enabled the help document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>

            <service name="Demo_rest_ConsoleApp.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8763/TEST/"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>

                <endpoint address=""
                          binding="webHttpBinding"
                          contract="Demo_rest_ConsoleApp.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="ESEndPointBehavior"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ESEndPointBehavior">
                    <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>

            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1" maxConcurrentInstances="1" maxConcurrentSessions="1"/>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>

        </behaviors>
    
    </system.serviceModel>
    
</configuration>
```

[image]

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the relevant section of web.config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NativeAppConnectorWCFAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="NativeAppConnectorWCF">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="NativeAppConnectorWCFAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="NativeAppConnectorWCF" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```